# How to change the values from child window textbox which reflects on parent window records in a table?

Tags: angularjs

What i need is when i change the value from child window textbox the reflect should appear on parent window records in a table. And here is my parent.html.

-----index.html--------

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.0-beta.6" data-semver="1.4.0-beta.6" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0-beta.6/angular.js"></script>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
  <div ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="PeopleCtrl">
<form  method=post action=''  name=f1>   
<table  border="1" >
    <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th> Edit here</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="person in people">
        <td><span id="d" name='p_name'>{{person.id}}</span></td>
        <td><span id="c" name='q_name'>{{person.name}}</span></td>
        <td><span id="e" name='r_name'>{{person.age}}</span></td>
        <td><a href="#" ng-click="foo()">Edit</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
</div>
</div>
<script>
var myApp=angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('PeopleCtrl', function($scope,$window) {

    $scope.people = ([
    {
    id: 1,
    name: "Peter",
    age: 21},
{
    id: 2,
    name: "David",
    age: 20},
{
    id: 3,
    name: "Anil",
    age: 22}
    ])
  $scope.foo = function() {

    $window.open('index1.html');
 };
});
</script>
```

And here is my child window:

------index1.html-------

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<script data-require="angular.js@1.4.0-beta.6" data-semver="1.4.0-beta.6" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0-beta.6/angular.js"></script>
<script>

function post_value(){
opener.document.f1.p_name.value = document.frm.c_name.value;
opener.document.f1.q_name.value = document.frm.d_name.value;
opener.document.f1.r_name.value = document.frm.e_name.value;

self.close();
}

</script>

<title>(Type a title for your page here)</title>
</head>


<body ng-app="mainApp" > 

<div ng-controller='childController'>

  <form name="frm" method=post action=''>
<table border="0">
   <tr><td>Enter  id:</td><td><input id="d"  type="text"   name="c_name" ></td></tr>
   <tr><td>Enter name:</td><td><input id="c"  type="text"   name="d_name" ></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Enter age:</td><td><input id="e"  type="text"   name="e_name" ></td></tr>
   <tr><td><button onclick="post_value();">Save</button></td></tr>
</table>

</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is my plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/qF2zvp0VYY9wMvWzt3XK?p=preview

Comment: this cannot be done with different windows using your implementation, remember angular is for single page app. The work around is using websocket let two windows listen to events

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't open details in other window. Then you can't persist data in your app because there is no way to communicate between two windows.

I don't think so you should make this thing this complicated as you can make you app as SPA (Single Page Application), For that you need to use `ng-route` which will dynamically load the pages on basis of url changes.

Using below html

```
<div ng-view></div>
```

Then you need write configuration for you app, when to load which template with which controller

**Config**

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

```
myApp.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/people', {
        templateUrl: 'people.html',
        controller: 'PeopleCtrl'
      })
      .when('/people/:id', {
        templateUrl: 'details.html',
        controller: 'detailsCtrl'
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/people'
      });
  }
]);
```

[**Working Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/mjDEFtR0mtrLFaLtCb9e?p=preview) here

Comment: but if i click to save i'm getting an error messege

Comment: @anilchean that part is pending..you should do that..on click of that button details will gets saved and user will redirect to list page, take a look at plunkr which I update..